# Linux mv command and then shutdown

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, shutdown

I have this small bash script (simplified) which runs on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
tar zxvf fileNameHere.tgz  <-- Untar tgz file in $SRC_DIR
files=$(ls $SRC_DIR)
echo "Extracting $files"  >> $APP_LOG_DIR/update.log
mv $SRC_DIR/* $OUTPUT_DIR
shutdown -r now
```

I've noticed that, after rebooting, only sometimes files are not moved to target and I was wondering if that shutdown command could be the a problem. Is it necessary to call 'sync' before shutting down?

Comment: It is not necessary to call `sync` before shutting down. A normal shutdown like that cleanly shuts down and unmounts filesystems.

Comment: Thanks...I'll have to keep on searching which is causing that my files are not getting copied sometimes...

Comment: Are you creating files as they are being copied?

Comment: Btw.: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: I have a .tz file which is decompressed, then files are moved to another directory and finally a shutdown is performed

Comment: I mean a .tar.gz file

Answer (score 1):

Fixed script with comments:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Test if SRC_DIR and OUTPUT_DIR are actual directories
if [ -d "$SRC_DIR" ] && [ -d "$OUTPUT_DIR" ]; then

  # Populates the arguments array with the content
  # of SRC_DIR rather than parsing the output of ls
  set -- "$SRC_DIR/"*

  # Prints joined file entries of the arguments array
  # while stripping their leading directory path
  printf 'Extracting %s\n' "${*#*/}" >> "$APP_LOG_DIR/update.log"

  # Moves all the arguments array's entries (the actual 
  # content of the SRC_DIR) into OUTPUT_DIR
  mv -- "$@" "$OUTPUT_DIR/"
  shutdown -r now
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Do yo think that my code could lead to this strange behaviour? Files sometimes are copied fine but other times they are not.

Comment: Your code fail with files and paths containing spaces because your variables expansion as arguments are missing double quotes. Also it misses explicitely terminating the option flags with `--` so any path/file name with leading dash will be handled as option flags and may cause failure or unexpected/dangerous behavior.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your advices. I'll make all these changes you suggested. Nevertheless, all files and paths I've tried do not contain spaces nor leading dashes. Could a sync be needed any where?

Comment: You can extract directly into destination dir with tar.